# Pivoting data and complex annotations in Django ORM

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm

The ORM in Django lets us easily annotate (add fields to) querysets based on related data, hwoever I can't find a way to get multiple annotations for different filtered subsets of related data.

This is being asked in relation to [django-helpdesk](https://github.com/RossP/django-helpdesk/), an open-source Django-powered trouble-ticket tracker. I need to have data pivoted like this for charting and reporting purposes

Consider these models:

```
CHOICE_LIST = (
    ('open', 'Open'),
    ('closed', 'Closed'),
)

class Queue(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Issue(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    queue = models.ForeignKey(Queue)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CHOICE_LIST)
```

And this dataset:

**Queues:**

```
ID | Name
---+------------------------------
1  | Product Information Requests
2  | Service Requests
```

**Issues:**

```
ID | Queue | Status
---+-------+---------
1  | 1     | open
2  | 1     | open
3  | 1     | closed
4  | 2     | open
5  | 2     | closed
6  | 2     | closed
7  | 2     | closed
```

I would like to see an annotation/aggregate look something like this:

```
Queue ID | Name                          | open | closed
---------+-------------------------------+------+--------
1        | Product Information Requests  | 2    | 1
2        | Service Requests              | 1    | 3
```

This is basically a crosstab or pivot table, in Excel parlance. I am currently building this output using some custom SQL queries, however if I can move to using the Django ORM I can more easily filter the data dynamically without doing dodgy insertion of WHERE clauses in my SQL.

For "bonus points": How would one do this where the pivot field (`status` in the example above) was a date, and we wanted the columns to be months / weeks / quarters / days?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have Python, use it.

```
from collections import defaultdict
summary = defaultdict( int )
for issue in Issues.objects.all():
    summary[issue.queue, issue.status] += 1
```

Now your `summary` object has queue, status as a two-tuple key.  You can display it directly, using various template techniques.

Or, you can regroup it into a table-like structure, if that's simpler.

```
table = []
queues = list( q for q,_ in summary.keys() )
for q in sorted( queues ):
    table.append( q.id, q.name, summary.count(q,'open'), summary.count(q.'closed') )
```

You have lots and lots of Python techniques for doing pivot tables.

If you measure, you may find that a mostly-Python solution like this is actually faster than a pure SQL solution.  Why?  Mappings can be faster than SQL algorithms which require a sort as part of a GROUP-BY.

Comment: This solution will crumble if Issues table is large and can hardly be regarded as general.

Comment: For anyone reading this a few years later: I get `collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'count'` with python3 also theres a typo on `summary.count(q.'closed')`

Answer (score 3):

Django has added a lot of functionality to the ORM since this question was originally asked. The answer to how to pivot data since Django 1.8 is to use the Case/When [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/). And there is a third party app that will do that for you, [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pivot/1.6.1) and [documentation](https://github.com/martsberger/django-pivot)

Comment: [django-sql-explorer](https://github.com/groveco/django-sql-explorer) also does pivot tables.

Comment: django-sql-explorer is a good tool and the pivot table functionality may be useful in this case, but the original question was about how to do a pivot table in the ORM and django-sql-explorer does it in javascript after the ORM returns all the raw data.