# Pivot tables or crosstab queries in HTSQL

Tags: python

I've been looking into HTSQL to solve some ad-hoc query requirements for a client's admin system (managing holiday trips, passengers, etc).

Is HTSQL able produce pivot tables, or crosstab queries (as I think they are sometimes called)?

For example:
Count of Passengers by trip (rows) and charity supported (columns)

Here's example of producing pivot tables with Python:
[Pivoting data and complex annotations in Django ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958415/pivoting-data-and-complex-annotations-in-django-orm)

There is some mention of pivot tables and HTSQL here:

- http://clarkevans.com/tmp/spec.html
- https://docs.rexdb.com/manuals/rexdb/htsql/chart.html

...but none of these seem to work in my version of HTSQL (2.3.0).

Answer (score 3):

The current version of HTSQL v2 does not support pivot tables, though we plan to add them in the future.  You could still make an output like this if you know the list of columns in advance.  For instance, the query in [Pivoting data and complex annotations in Django ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958415/pivoting-data-and-complex-annotations-in-django-orm) could be written as:

```
/queue{*, count(issue?status='open'), count(issue?status='closed')}
```

or, using `define()`,

```
/queue.define(issue_num($status) := count(issue?status=$status))
      {*, issue_num('open'), issue_num('closed')}
```