# How can I access multiple Querysets in a template in the same cycle?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset

I am transferring different similar Querysets to a template. Eg. qset01, qset02, ... qset10.
The number of Querysets in known and can be transferred as well.
How can I access these Querysets in a template in a cycle in the same iteration level. 
When I iterate through a single query, the code is:

```
{% for i in qset01 %}
    {{i.field_01}}
{% endfor %}
```

What would it look like for many Querysets?
This is what I need

```
{% for more_complex_iteration %}
    {{qset01.field_01}}, {{qset02.field_01}}, ... {{qset09.field_01}}
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively multiple querysets could be joined. But I do not know how.
qset01 has data

```
country_1, 100
country_2, 200
country_3, 300
```

qset02 has data

```
country_1, 111
country_2, 222
country_3, 333
```

qset03 has data

```
country_1, 101
country_2, 202
country_3, 303
```

final queryset should have this data

```
country_1, 100, 111, 101
country_2, 200, 222, 202
country_3, 300, 333, 303
```

view.py

```
 def function(request):
    iteration_result = "i_01" #this is the first iteration result only
                              #from ["i_01","i_02", ... "i_09"]
    qset1 = BigTable.objects.values(
        'deb_nr_f__dcountry__wcode_f__code',
        'deb_nr_f__dcountry__wcode_f__code_name',
        ).annotate(
            tmp_code=F('deb_nr_f__dcountry__wcode_f__code'),
            tmp_descr=F('deb_nr_f__dcountry__wcode_f__code_name')
            ).values('tmp_code','tmp_descr'
        ).order_by('-abs_2016__sum'
        ).annotate(
            abs_2016__sum=Sum('abs_2016'),
        ).filter(id_nr_f__ie_code__unomer_f__nomer=iteration_result,
        )
```

Model definition

```
 class BigTable(models.Model):
    deb_nr_f = models.ForeignKey(Debitor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='debitor_fnr', verbose_name='Debitor FNr', blank=True, null=True)
    id_nr_f = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='material', verbose_name='Material', blank=True, null=True)
    abs_2016 = models.IntegerField('Abs. 2016', default=0)
    abs_2017 = models.IntegerField('Abs. 2017', default=0)
    abs_2018 = models.IntegerField('Abs. 2018', default=0)
    abs_2019 = models.IntegerField('Abs. 2019', default=0)
    abs_2020 = models.IntegerField('Abs. 2020', default=0)
```

I would like to SEPARATELY filter the table with a number (9) of different "filter"-queries. I need one final Queryset, like this one, where every column (except the first one) is a result of 9 separate "filter"-queries.

```
country_1, 100, 111, 101
country_2, 200, 222, 202
country_3, 300, 333, 303
```

Comment: It might be better to join those data sources in a single queryset.

Comment: I thought about it. How can I join many similar querysets in a single queryset? The different querysets have the same structure and the same length. Thank you

Comment: Show your model definition.

Comment: pls see above. I have updated the question.

Comment: So you're looking for a "PIVOT". Does this answer your question? [Pivoting data and complex annotations in Django ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958415/pivoting-data-and-complex-annotations-in-django-orm)

Comment: yes, it does. THank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
querySets = [ qset01, qset02, ... ]
context = { 'querySets': querySets, ....}


{% for set in querySets %}
    {{ set.country_1 }}
{% endfor %}
{% for set in querySets %}
    {{ set.country_2 }}
{% endfor %}
{% for set in querySets %}
    {{ set.country_3 }}
{% endfor %}
```

if you want to do something like this

```
{% for country_line in querySets %}
    {% for country in country_line %}
        {{ country }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You would need your data ordered as

```
[
    [ country_1, country_1, country_1 ],
    [ country_2, country_2, country_2 ],
    [ country_3, country_3, country_3 ],
]
```

Comment: I do not need many consequental independent iterations in the template. I need one iteration, probably with embedded loops. In the first iteration I need separately these three data fields `100, 111, 101`. In the second iteration these `200, 222, 201`